# about receiving float on Atmega32 from matlab

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, matlab

I want to receive a float on Atmega32 from matlab. I display the output on an lcd, but i receive 0.000, can any one help me? Please ...

**matlab code**

```
s=serial('COM1','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(s)
fwrite(s,170,'uint8');//header frame
fwrite(s,1.2,'float');//the data to be sent
```

**ATmega32 code**

```
union {
  signed long l;
  float f;
} data;

int main(void)
{   
  DDRA=0xff;//for LCD
  DDRB=0xff;//for LCD 
  data.l;
  char value[8];
  usart_init();
  Lcd8_Init();

  while(1)
  { 
    if(uart_receive()==0xAA)
    { 
      //header,0xAA=170
      Lcd8_Set_Cursor(0,0);
      Lcd8_Write_String("Float");
      _delay_ms(100);

      data.l=(long)uart_receive();
      data.l=(long)(data.l||(uart_receive()<<8));
      data.l=(long)(data.l||(uart_receive()<<16));
      data.l=(long)(data.l||(uart_receive()<<24));

      dtostrf(data.f,8,3,value);//convert float to string 

      Lcd8_Clear();
      Lcd8_Set_Cursor(0,0);
      for(int i=0;i<8;i++) Lcd8_Write_Char(value[i]); 
   }

}}
```

Comment: I would say you wrote the value into the long member of data `data.l`, but you tried to convert the float member of data `data.f` to a string. `data.f` is still 0.0

Comment: data.l contains the float value sent from matlab..so how to convert data.l to float?

Comment: You send a float value from mathlab byte wise to the AVR and store 4 bytes of the float value into a long variable of the AVR. That's complicated, becaus you have to know several things. How is the structure of a float in matlab? Is this the same on a AVR? I would suggest you send a String with the value from mathlab to the AVR and on the AVR convert the string into a float. (I know atof() for this reason. You use an AVR lib I don't know. In matlab you can use the fprintf function to convert the float to a string and send it to the AVR.